# Pandas function read_csv returning SyntaxError: invalid token unexpectedly

Tags: python, pandas, csv, syntax-error

I am trying to simply read in a dataframe from a csv that is stored locally on my computer. The data is in a csv and is of the format:

```
date,total_bytes
2018-09-02,1.96E+14
2018-09-04,1.94E+14
2018-09-09,2.15E+14
...
```

My code looks like:

```
from pandas import read_csv
from pandas import datetime
from matplotlib import pyplot
series = 
read_csv('/Users/taylorjewell/Desktop/dataset_size_daily.csv')
print(series.head())
series.plot()
pyplot.show()
```

When I try to run this file I get: 
File "dataset_size_daily.csv", line 2
   2018-09-02,1.96E+14
   Syntax Error: Invalid token

Where am I going wrong, your help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What is the separator you're using? There might be an extra comma where it shouldn't be, thus invalidating the whole file.

Comment: I have validated the input which is only 52 rows to make sure this isnt the case and I am still getting the same error :(

Comment: Please open your csv with a text editor and paste exactly the top few rows into the body of your post so we can reproduce. Right now, I cannot reproduce your error.

Comment: that is exactly the top few rows of the csv, are you telling me that it is running successfully on your machine?

Answer (score 0):

As weird as it might seem, it looks like you're trying to execute your CSV file as Python code, instead of the actual python script.  I was even able to reproduce your error by running `python asdf.csv`:

```
sh-5.0$ cat asdf.csv
date,total_bytes
2018-09-02,1.96E+14
2018-09-04,1.94E+14
2018-09-09,2.15E+14
sh-5.0$ python asdf.csv
  File "asdf.csv", line 2
    2018-09-02,1.96E+14
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
sh-5.0$
```

So... it should go without saying, but run the .py file, not the .csv one...

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to read CSV file without the extenction, it should be like pd.read_csv('data.csv')

Comment: If that's the case, he should get `FileNotFoundError` not `SyntaxError`